# Which aircraft manufacturers still include Vertical Situation Displays (VSD) feature in their cockpits?

Tags: navigation, avionics, display

I'm curious about the aircraft manufacturer names who still interested in including the VSD on lower part of Nav Display (I read about Boeing 737 only). Are there any other guys on this filed still? I know this would be useful during the landing and takeoff.

Comment: Do you mean airlines?  The aircraft can be configured to show this or not.

Comment: Aircraft manufacturers like Boeing, Airbus etc.. Is this technology outdated?

Comment: What do you mean by **vertical** situation display? I only know vertical *speed indicator* and *horizontal* situation display.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## VSD

Boeing have a [patent](http://www.google.com/patents/US7783393) on a VSD (Vertical Situation Display), which is part of the [Honeywell EGPWS](https://aerospace.honeywell.com/news/vertical-situation-display-capable-egpws-available-for-737ng-retrofit) (Enhanced Ground Proximity Warning System) which first appeared as an option on 737s about twelve years ago I think.

> The system will be offered by early **2003** as a customer option on in-production 737s and by retrofit on 737-600/-700/-800/-900 airplanes already in service. Implementation of the system on other Boeing models is under consideration.

<sup>- Boeing ["Aero" magazine](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/aero_20/vsd_story.html)</sup>

[image]

I don't know if Boeing offer licences at acceptable terms to their competitors, or if Honeywell make available, to other aircraft makers, products that incorporate features licensed from those patents.

## CFIT

It is possible that other manufacturers have equivalent options for alerting pilots of potential CFIT (Controlled Flight Into Terrain).

## TAWS & EGPWS

The FAA, for example, requires aircraft be fitted with systems that comply with [TAWS (Terrain Awareness Warning Systems)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrain_awareness_and_warning_system) requirements. EGPWS systems satisfy that requirement.

TAWS requires a terrain awareness display but I dont think it requires something specifically like Boeing's VSD.

Airbus for example, on at least their A350 and A380 models, have a navigation display that incorporates "vertical flightpath data". I guess they don't call it a VSD. They also have what I think is a fairly common type of terrain display showing "peaks" ahead of the aircraft.

[image] 
[image]

<sup>- Sources: [FlightGlobal](http://www.flightglobal.com/news/articles/airbus-hopes-a350-flightdeck-offers-best-of-both-worlds-with-a380-technology-and-high-205721/) and Airbus</sup>

## RNP

It may be that some of the issues addressed by the VSD are, for many airports in mountainous terrain, taken care of by [RNP (Required Navigation Performance)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Required_navigation_performance) which prescribes the required navigational accuracy of the aircraft's navigation systems. Generally the aircraft is required to be able to follow an approach path that consists of a sequence of curved three-dimensional paths to the runway that avoids terrain. I imagine this path is pre-programmed into the navigation systems along with the go-around paths.

[image]

Comment: So VSD would be only on Boeing aircraft, other manufacturers like Airbus do have equivalent Technology, but it is not called as VSD, instead it is CFIT. is that right?

Comment: `CFIT` is "Controlled Flight Into Terrain" (or "Unintentional Landing") and is to be avoided at all times, as it usually costs lives. `VSD` is Boeing's term for their `EGPWS` that meets the FAAs `TAWS` requirements. Airbus have a similar system, but with a different name than `VSD`, who's job is to help the pilots avoid `CFIT`. (For definitions of the `TLA`s, see RedGrittyBrick's excellent answer.)

Comment: @FreeMan Also known as "cumulo granitus".

Comment: The VSD can SHOW the terrain data from EGPWS, but it is not PART OF the EGPWS.  It's common to have EGPWS without the VSD.  In fact, the more common use of a VSD is to show the vertical path of the aircraft in relation to the flightplan in the FMC and crossing restrictions that are programmed into this plan.  It's an enhancement to the "moving map" display, but it's a mistake to equate it to EGPWS.  They're not the same, and EGPWS has been around much longer.

Comment: The Boeing 747-8 and 787 have the same system installed.

Answer (score 3):

There are similar vertical profile displays available on Boeing 787, Airbus A380 and Airbus A350 aircraft.

Here is an image of the 787's flight deck showing the VSD on the copilot's side:

[image]
Source: [Airliners.net](https://www.airliners.net/photo/Boeing/Boeing-787-8-Dreamliner/2112928)

Comment: Good info...do you have sources to include here by chance?

Comment: Below is a link to a 787 flight deck picture on airliners.net. The VSD is shown at the bottom of the navigation display presented on the right inboard screen. A380 (possibly A350) can be found on that site, too. Another useful resource is smartcockpit.com, but I haven't looked at it in years. Link: http://www.airliners.net/photo/Boeing/Boeing-787-8-Dreamliner/2112928/L/&sid=d43bc3372c1fc5a10481e6281fba2d06

Answer (score 0):

For the smaller aircraft market (and the big guys for that matter) many of the [common EFB applications will display this information](https://foreflight.com/support/video-library/watch/?v=profile-view).

[image]
([source](https://foreflight.files.wordpress.com/2016/01/heli-profile-view.png))